# angular how to get the params in url

Tags: angular

i have a sub router under route 'welcome', and I try to get the params labeled 'name', but it seems this router doesn't work, confused me a lot. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!

```
const routes: Routes= [
  {path:'', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'welcome', component: LoginComponent,
    children:
      [
        {path:':name', component:WelcomeComponent}
      ]
  },
  {path:'**', component: PageerrorComponent}
]
```

and in my welcomcompont:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeRouter.params.subscribe((params)=>{
      this.username = params['name'];
    })
  }
```

Comment: whats the type of activeRouter ?

Comment: i used [private activeRouter: ActivatedRoute] thanks!